# How to properly change the vertices position programmatically for a link in JointJS

Tags: css, jointjs

I am changing the vertices position for the link using the following code:

```
var vertices = link.get('vertices');
for(var j=0;j < vertices.length; j++){
   var vertex = vertices[j];
   vertex.x += differenceX;
   vertex.y += differenceY;
}
```

However, even though the link vertices seem to be nicely translated, when hovering over the link, the link-tools appear in the previous position as shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

I already tried different things including calls to

- `paper.render()`
- `linkview.update()`

unfortunately none of them seem to work...

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Backbone.Model.prototype.set` to update the attributes instead of modifying them directly. Otherwise no `change` event is triggered on the model and the view does not update itself.

```
var oldVertices = link.get('vertices');
var newVertices = [];

for(var j=0; j < oldVertices.length; j++){
   var oldVertex = oldVertices[j];
   // Create a new object, so you are not modifying
   // the previous model's attributes.
   // Backbone Model would not trigger a change event if the previous
   // and the new value are `deep` equal.
   var newVertex = { x: oldVertex.x, y: oldVertex.y }
   newVertex.x += differenceX;
   newVertex.y += differenceY;
   newVertices.push(newVertex);
}

link.set('vertices', newVertices);
```

Comment: Cool it almost works with this new version. The vertices are shown properly in their new positions, however the arrowheads are slightly out of position... Any ideas why that's happening?

Comment: mmm I'm not sure I can do that easily since the application has a lot of dependencies. I'll see what I can do and will let you know ;)

Comment: Thanks @Roman it works well. With ES6, the loop can simply be: `for(let v of oldVertices){ newVertices.push(g.point(v.x + diffX, v.y + diffY)) }`